# ɵ (Theta-like) symbol in Angular 2+ source code

Tags: angular, open-source, notation

After a deep dive into an Angular 4.3.* source code I was bumping into ɵ symbol quite often. For example, in [async pipe source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.2/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L43-L145) we see the usage of `ɵisPromise(_)` and `ɵisObservable(_)` functions.
So now I wonder why Angular team decided to use it? And what does it mean?

It seems that Angular devs mark methods/modules with ɵ to emphasize they are some kind of inner entities that should never be imported. But I didn`t find any authoritative proofs.

After some deeper research I found another interesting fact:
basically ɵ is a letter in several Latin-script alphabets (according to wiki was included into the Azerbaijani alphabet used between 1922 and 1933) but it resembles Greek  θ (Theta) letter. After some googling I managed to find a Math formula (successfully forgotten after graduation) of angular velocity calculation, where Theta letter meant angle.
So maybe this is a kind of humour?

Comment: https://twitter.com/yurzui/status/1064145423496110085

Comment: It **is** a programming question in that it's important to know if this is just one company's style guide or a recommended general practice for Typescript or JavaScript.

Comment: @yurzui unwrapping your tweet to expose your mentioned link directly: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14566#issuecomment-282063947

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> So now I wonder why Angular team decided to use it? And what does it
>   mean?

Yes, it marks methods as internal/private. Here is the quote from [the article](https://medium.com/@urish/a-deep-deep-deep-deep-deep-dive-into-the-angular-compiler-5379171ffb7a) that was written by [Uri Shaked](https://twitter.com/UriShaked) who got this information from the Angular core team members:

> The first thing you many notice is a lot of obscure method names,
>   starting with the letter ɵ (Greek Theta) followed by 3 other English
>   letters (e.g. ɵvid). The letter ɵ is used by the Angular team to
>   indicate that some method is private to the framework and must not be
>   called directly by the user, as the API for these method is not
>   guaranteed to stay stable between Angular versions (in fact, I would
>   say it’s almost guaranteed to break).

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not θ *Greek small letter theta* (U+03B8) but ɵ *Latin small letter barred o* (U+0275).

Comment: @Taosique That does make more sense: to call those internal/private methods **barred** ;-) As in _"barred / banned from"_ or _restricted._ 
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/barred